# Minecraft 1.13.1 Villagers won't breed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

This is my attempt at a village breeder. They each have stacks of carrots in their inventory, but no hearts show up and they won't breed.

[image]

This is what's below the part you see here, and the bottom is 7 blocks below where the villagers are. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How long has this been going on? And are there any other villages nearby?

Answer (score 1):

The two things that would prevent a villager from breeding would be:

- **Not enough doors:** If there aren't enough valid doors, then the village is at its 'cap' and no villagers will breed
- **Not enough happiness:** If the villagers aren't happy, they won't breed. You can increase their happiness by trading with them.

Once you trade with the villagers a few times, and double check to make sure all the doors are legitimate, you should see them breed.